# get data on particular timings of the day in a month in SQL

Tags: sql

How can I retrieve data on time range where tickets issued between the times of 6am - 9:15am for the past month.
I tried this but was wrong.Its in oracle and to_char is not function name in SQL. how can i do that in sql.

```
select * 
  from [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]
 where t_date_time_issued > sysdate - 30
   and to_char(t_date_time_issed, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '06:00:00' 
   and to_char(t_date_time_issued, 'hh24:mi:ss') <= '09:15:00'
```

Comment: Please post why the result of this query is wrong. Is it because of the typo in line 4?

Comment: to_timestamp() as Rajiv said in the below answer

Comment: @juergend: i assume that your edit was misleading since OP seems not to use oracle. That's why he says: _"Its in oracle and to_char is not function name in SQL. how can i do that in sql"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want it in SQL-Server("Its in oracle and to_char is not function name in SQL"), you can cast the `datetme` to `time`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [dbo].[tickets] 
WHERE  t_date_time_issued > DATEADD(mm, - 30, GetDate()) 
AND Cast(t_date_time_issued as TIME) between '06:00' and '09:10'
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/400c0/1)</kbd>

Comment: Type TIME is not a defined system type.in sql server managment studio Instead I used DatePart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_timestamp()` in stead of `to_char`. Details about `to_timestamp()` is: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2118.htm#OLADM696

Hope will help!

Comment: I want to know it in SQL not in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [ICPS].[DBO].[tickets]
WHERE
    t_date_time_issued BETWEEN add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), - 1) AND (
        TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - (1/24/60/60))
AND TO_CHAR(t_date_time_issed, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '06:00:00'
AND TO_CHAR(t_date_time_issed, 'HH24:MI:SS') <= '09:15:00'
```

Comment: TRUNC' is not a recognized function name. in sql server management studio.

Comment: My bad I believe I have seen oracle tag on your question earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]
    WHERE   convert (datetime,t_date_time_issued,101) 
          between convert(datetime,'2013/11/01',101) and convert (datetime,'2013/12/04',101)
    AND datepart(hour,t_date_time_issued) between '06' and '09'
```